# How to speed up (very remote) overloaded server connection

Tags: performance, time, timeout, high-load

I'm living in France and I need to load a page from a far far away server (still in the same galaxy). "Far" is Canada to me, meaning over 8 000km of internet cable.

The problem is, this server is **very** overloaded. Millions of people connect to this server in the same time. So I only get **very very** slow response or even time out from the server. 
(At night this serveur is very fast)

How can I speed up my requests during this overloaded time?
Do you think having a VPN in Canada can speed it up?

Comment: Is the content dynamic or static?

Comment: @Ztyx dynamic HTML only (I keep the cache in memory)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's unlikely that the distance from France to Canada is making any significant difference, or that getting a Canadian VPN would help. If the server is overloaded, then there's nothing that you can do except for doing your download at a quieter time. The server's operators need to upgrade it.

The only exception to this would be if the server's external Internet bandwidth is what's overloaded and you can get a VPN connection that uses a different Internet connection to connect to the same local network as the server is on. But that's very unlikely.

Answer (score 3):

You can set up a caching proxy (assuming we're talking about HTTP - and potentially HTTPS if you are okay to set up HTTPS interception) such as Squid to cache the server's responses.

Tinkering with the refresh patterns and using non-standard options (such as ignoring Cache-Control headers) may yield even better results at the expense of breaking the HTTP standard and possibly serving outdated content.